# Primefaces performance when having a lot of Buttons

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I generate a Table where each row has two Buttons:

```
<p:button outcome="#{navigation.actionDetails}" icon="fa fa-info-circle" title="Details">
    <f:param name="#{webParameter.client}" value="#{userSession.client.shortName}" />
    <f:param name="#{webParameter.actionId}" value="#{action.id}" />
</p:button>
```

Now I have ~2000 rows, which results in ~4000 Buttons per page.

Now when using IE11, the page renders really really slow (~3 Minutes). FF/Chrome: < 10 seconds.

I found out when changing the Buttons to Links the behaviour is much much better. I suspect it results from not generating javascript code for the buttons:

```
</button><script id="filterForm:j_idt119_s" type="text/javascript">PrimeFaces.cw("Button","widget_filterForm_j_idt119",{id:"filterForm:j_idt119"});</script>
```

Now my Idea was to create `p:link` instead of `p:button` and to style it like buttons. Do you have any other/better ideas?

Comment: don't use 4000 buttons... Makes the ui crowed anyway. Use 'selection' and one button below the table with a 'show details'

Comment: Lazy table, pagination, filtering. PrimeFaces has got it all.